# How can i set a default account in Heirloom-mailx?

Tags: ubuntu, email, mailx

How can i set a default account in Heirloom-mailx?

I have defined an account in `/etc/nail.rc` that is usable via `mail -A accountname` but i'd like to set this account to be used by default so i can omit the `-A` parameter.

The man page under http://heirloom.sourceforge.net/mailx/mailx.1.html doesn't seem to include setting defaults.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to maintain multiple accounts but select one by default, add an account command after the accounts are defined to select it

Example rc file:

```
account myimap {
    set folder=imap://user@host
    set record=+Sent
    set imap-keepalive="5"
}
account local {
    set folder=.local/maildir
    unset record
}
# Now select myimap as default account on startup:
account myimap
```

Now on invoking mailx, it will connect to myimap, but you can still switch between the two accounts with `account local` and `account myimap` (and whatever other accounts you define) in interactive mode, or pick which one using `mailx -A myimap` or `mailx -A local` (and whatever other accounts) when invoking from the commandline.

(tested with Heirloom mailx version 12.5 6/20/10)

Answer (score 7):

Just get rid of the account wrapper you put around the settings.

**nail.rc**

Instead of:

```
# other mail config
...

account gmail {
  set smtp-use-starttls
  set smtp-auth=login
  set smtp=smtp://smtp.gmail.com:587
  set smtp-auth-user=username@gmail.com
  set smtp-auth-password="blahblah"
}
```

Use:

```
# other mail config
...

set smtp-use-starttls
set smtp-auth=login
set smtp=smtp://smtp.gmail.com:587
set smtp-auth-user=username@gmail.com
set smtp-auth-password="blahblah"
```

It will use those as the default settings.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Will check when i get back to this project and accept the answer then.